# C++ Class getting input

Tags: c++, class

I wanna ask you quick question. How can get the name, surname, id and age as an input? These are must be taken **as input** and variables must be private. How should I code about it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace  std;

class Employee{
private:
    string  Name;
    string Surname;
    int IdNumber;
    int age;
public:
    Employee(string isim,string soyisim,int idnumarasi,int yas){

        Name = isim;
        Surname = soyisim;
        IdNumber = idnumarasi;
        age = yas;
    }
      void printEmployee(){

          cout << Name << endl;
          cout << Surname << endl;
          cout << IdNumber <<endl;
          cout << age << endl;
    }


};


int main() {



    Employee employee("John","Lares",12,25);

    employee.printEmployee();


    return 0;
}
```

Edited version. I used getline but still cant reach the private variables. How can reach the private variables. Is the only way getter setter functions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace  std;

class Employee{
private:
    string  Name;
    string Surname;
    int IdNumber;
    int age;
public:
    Employee(){

        Name = isim;
        Surname = soyisim;
        IdNumber = idnumarasi;
        age = yas;
    }
      void printEmployee(){

          cout << Name << endl;
          cout << Surname << endl;
          cout << IdNumber <<endl;
          cout << age << endl;
    }


};


int main() {



    Employee employee();

    getline(cin,employee.Name);
    getline(cin,employee.Surname);
    getline(cin,employee.IdNumber);
    getline(cin,employee.age);

    employee.printEmployee();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will find an explanation of how to do this basic task in every C++ textbook. Have you tried looking in your textbook, for an answer? Is there something in your textbook that's unclear to you? If so, you can [edit] your question, add a brief excerpt that you don't understand, and explain your confusion. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question; which gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: overload the `>>` operator?

Comment: I'm farily certain, @AlanBirtles, that this subject matter is completely unfamiliar to the OP.

Comment: I edited the code. Can you check it again ? @AlanBirtles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to use the constructor you have defined

```
int main()
{
    string name, surname;
    int id, age;
    cin >> name >> surname >> id >> age;       // read user input
    Employee someone(name, surname, id, age);  // create employee from user input
    ...
}
```

Using a constructor is the normal way to give class member variables their initial values.

Another more complicated way is to overload `operator>>`

Comment: Is this method uses variables inside of private ? or it just declares new variables?

Comment: It declares new variables and then uses those variables and the constructor to set the private variables in the class. That's what constructors do.